# Trying to add and remove table rows with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, tablerow

I am trying to add and remove table rows with jQuery, added rows contain a remove link, which for some reason doesn't work on the generated elements, even though I use on.

Here my code:

```
$("#target").click(function() {
$('#myTable tr:last').after('<tr><td>Bla</td><td><div class="remove">REMOVE</div></td></tr>');
});
$(".remove").on('click', function(event) {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

http://jsbin.com/ucopun/1/

What could be the problem?

The remove link is supposed to remove the whole row in which it is located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `on()`, you still need to bind the event to a container element that exists on the page already. I think this is what you want:

```
$("#myTable").on('click', '.remove', function(event) {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: is that only for elements appended to the dom? (aka old live)

Comment: I believe it's very similar if not identical to `live`. The idea is that the bound event will trigger on the container, and then the function will only be called if the actual target matches the provided selector.

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. See this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hyguF/1)**.

```
$("#myTable").on('click', '.remove', function(event) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});​
```

Since you're adding elements that don't exist when the code runs, you need to use `.on()` to bind to an element that does exist when the code runs.

As the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/) state:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page.

Also, I find `.closest('tr')` easier to follow than `.parent().parent()`

Comment: great, ty for the explenation!

Answer (score 1):

I would bind the event to the table and delegate it to the button

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

```
$("#myTable").delegate('.remove','click' , function(event) {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

**EDIT**: seems like delegate is superseeded by on (As of jQuery 1.7 - reference http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.

Comment: Thanks - updated my answer :) Keeping it as it would depend on the Jquery version he is using.

Answer (score 1):

Use live function

```
$('.remove',$("#myTable")).live('click',function(){
  $(this).parents('tr:first').remove();
});
```

​http://jsfiddle.net/B8wSq/2/