# Store generated HTML in variable

Tags: jquery, html, code-generation, innerhtml

I have a simple jQuery table editor, and want to be able to store the whole table in a variable. Later the state of the table will be saved, sort of a mini CMS.

I tried using HTML, but it doesn't work for the generated elements.

What is the best way to to do this? Also, is what `.html()` returns safe, or should I not use it because of browser differences in `innerHTML`?

```
$("#target").click(function() {
    $('#myTable tr:last').after('<tr><td>Bla</td><td><div class="remove">REMOVE</div></td></tr>');
});

$("#myTable").on('click', '.remove', function(event) {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});

var table = $("#myTable").html();
$("button").click(function() {
    $(".result").html(table);
});
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to store the HTML content of `#myTable` in a JavaScript variable? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: For dynamically generated elements you should use `on` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844202/trying-to-add-and-remove-table-rows-with-jquery

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan I don't think he's asking how to add rows, more how to save the resulting structure. I might be wrong, though.

Comment: i want to store the whole content of the table in a variable, the generated content and the static content

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of what you're trying to achieve? Also, have you tried putting the line `var table = $("#myTable").html();` inside the button's click handler?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ucopun/9/ here it is

Comment: tried the line inside the click function, works, but why?!

Comment: Because you're writing it to a variable when the DOM is ready (i.e. before any modifications are made), so the variable only ever contains the initial markup, BEFORE user modifications have occurred.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try updating the click handler to the following:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var table = $("#myTable").html();
    $(".result").html(table);
});
```

See it working here: http://jsbin.com/ucopun/11

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to store the whole table in a different element or in a variable ?

If you want to store it in a variable then

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    var table_html = '<table id="myTable">' + $('#myTable').html() + '</table>';
    // alert(table_html);
});
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/84ETb/

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just call `html()` after you've done your modifications (i.e. when the button is clicked, not when the DOM is ready)

```
var the_content = $('#myTable').html();
```

Comment: i did, but this doesnt get the generated html, see my fiddle http://jsbin.com/ucopun/9/

Comment: @user1721135 You will have to bump up to the parent and then grab the html from the parent. $('#myTable').parent().html();

Comment: You're not calling `.html()` when the button is clicked, but rather when the document loads. Move your line into the button click, and it works as you wish: http://jsbin.com/ucopun/10/

Comment: No they weren't... look at the times of the posts. The accepted answer was posted 5 minutes after mine...